# Why does pop take a parameter in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, arguments, callstack

Consider:

```
popl   %ebp
```

It seems the `%ebp` is unnecessary, because the `pop` operation of stack doesn't need a parameter.

Why does it make sense?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From *[x86 Assembly Guide](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Eevans/cs216/guides/x86.html)*:

> **pop** — Pop stack
>
> The pop instruction removes the 4-byte data element from the top of the hardware-supported stack into the specified operand (i.e. register or memory location). It first moves the 4 bytes located at memory location [SP] into the specified register or memory location, and then increments SP by 4.
>
> *Syntax* 
> pop <reg32> 
> pop <mem>
>
> *Examples* 
> pop edi — pop the top element of the stack into EDI. 
> pop [ebx] — pop the top element of the stack into memory at the four bytes starting at location EBX.

Another good reference is *[x86 Assembly](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly)* and it is available [in PDF form](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/en/1/11/X86_Assembly.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

This parameter sets the destination.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on [Andrey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554123/why-does-pop-take-a-parameter-in-assembly/2554129#2554129), in addition to incrementing the stack pointer over the popped element, the popped element is also copied to a destination address or register.

The instruction you gave is more or less equivalent to the two instructions (Intel syntax)

```
add esp, 4               # increment the stack pointer
mov ebp, [esp - 4]       # load what ESP was pointing to
```

which I think is this in att (gas) syntax

```
add $4, %esp
mov -4(%esp), %ebp
```

Of course `pop` doesn't modify FLAGS (so imagine doing the `add` with LEA), and it's not interruptible between the load and add.

For the special case of `pop esp`, doing the load 2nd in the pseudocode replicates the [actual documented behaviour](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pop) of incrementing *before* data from the old top-of-stack location is written to ESP.  And of doing the increment before address calculation for a memory-destination pop using `%esp` as part of the addressing mode, like `popl 12(%esp, %edx, 4)`